# c# ef Migration with DbContext - NETCore.App 1.1.0 EntityFrameworkCore 1.1.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I want to seed my database in my web project and reading through anything i can find it seems a tough task.  I figure you could get the `DbContext` in then i would be able to just add it to the `Up()` in the migration file.  This is what I have

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
using student.Data;
using student.Models;
using System.Linq;

namespace student.Migrations
{
    public partial class INITAL_seed : Migration
    {

        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public INITAL_seed()
        {}
        public INITAL_seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            // Look for any students.
            if (_context.invoice_state.Any())
            {
                return;   // DB has been seeded
            }

            var invoice_states = new invoice_state[]
            {
                new invoice_state{title="Approval Denied",alias="approval_false"},
                new invoice_state{title="Needing Finish",alias="start_finish"},
                new invoice_state{title="Needing Approval",alias="approve_finish"},
                new invoice_state{title="Needing Send",alias="send_finish"},
                new invoice_state{title="Locked",alias="lock_finish"}
            };
            foreach (invoice_state IN in invoice_states)
            {
                _context.invoice_state.Add(IN);
            }
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

the trouble is that it need the parameter-less construct. I need to be able to get that fixed and I would believe that would work then.  So if i correct

```
        public INITAL_seed()
        {}
        public INITAL_seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
```

to something like

```
        public INITAL_seed()
        {
            _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
```

I would be set.  That doesn't work because i need to get options to it since this is the `DbContext` class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using student.Models;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using student.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;


namespace student.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }

        public DbSet<invoice_state> invoice_state { get; set; }



    }
}
```

My question is how to do this with out tons of new wiring.

Comment: Surprised no needs to seed the DB and that there is little out there on it, but for now i bypassed by adding an API method that had the adds i want and then securing that so it can't be hit with out my IP and a key in the url.  Hokey yes, but it worked for now ;-)